# Matlab: Extract Image in polar representation from Cartesian

Tags: image, matlab, polar-coordinates, cartesian

I m trying to compute an efficient way to transform an image in cartesian coordinates into a polar representation. I know some functions such as ImToPolar are doing it and it works perfectly but takes a considerable much time for big images, especially when they require to be processed back and forth.

Here´s my input image:

[image: input image]

and then I generate a polar mesh using a cartesian mesh centered at 0 and the function `cart2pol()`. Finally, I plot my image using `mesh(theta, r, Input)`.

And here´s what I obtain:

[image: output image]

Its exactly the image I need and it´s the same as `ImToPolar` or maybe better.

Since MATLAB knows how to compute it, does anybody know how to extract a matrix in polar representation from this output? Or maybe a fast (like in fast fourier transform) way to compute a Polar transform (and inverse) on MATLAB?

Comment: Do you need to interpolate your polar image onto a regular grid? Your method results in non-square "pixels"

Comment: [Here](https://fossies.org/dox/octave-4.0.3/cart2pol_8m_source.html) is OCTAVE's source for cart2pol. It might require some changes to use. I have no clue if it would be faster. You might be able to adapt it. I would _guess_ MATLAB has a lot of overhead that you might be able to get rid of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pol2cart` and `meshgrid` and `interp2` are sufficient to create the result:

```
I=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYSyb.png');
[r, c,~] = size(I);
%rgb image can be converted to indexed image to prevent excessive copmutation for each color
[idx, mp] = rgb2ind(I,32);
% add offset to image coordinates
x = (1:c)-(c/2);
y = (1:r)-(r/2);
% create distination coordinates in polar form so value of image can be interpolated in those coordinates
% angle ranges from 0 to 2 * pi and radius assumed that ranges from 0 to 400
% linspace(0,2*pi, 200) leads to a stretched image try it!
[xp yp] = meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi), linspace(0,400));
%translate coordinate from polar to image coordinates
[xx , yy] = pol2cart(xp,yp);
% interpolate pixel values for unknwon coordinates
out = interp2(x, y, idx, xx, yy);
% save the result to a file
imwrite(out, mp, 'result.png')
```